# Websockets from windows application

Tags: c#, windows, websocket, signalr

Im creating a web application that can view a few database tables. You can even update the tables from the web application. Everything works fine, but I want the tables also to be updated in realtime when the tables are changed from another client! And even from my windows application. I've heard that you can use websockets between clients. But Can you also use websockets from a windows program to communicate with a webserver? (on the same computer)

All client examples Ive found so far uses javascript, so I think the answer is no, but hope Im wrong. I was planning to use signalR. 
Im writing in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Websockets are not natively in the .NET library for clients. But there are good 3rd party libraries which are free.

I have used WebSocket4Net. https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks alot! There is no example project somewhere with this library?

Comment: Demo code is on that page, and you can get the package from nuget inside visual studio. Don't think about the versioning. It's robust and fault tolerant. That means it automatically reconnects etc. "It just works".

Comment: I havent tried the client code yet, but when I go to the superwebsocket project, thats linked as a recommended server i cannot run the examples there. The server seems to disconnect the whole time. I tried the basicconsole version.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is an official IETF wire protocol that can be used by any language.  WebSocket is also a W3C official JavaScript API, but there are other language bindings that mimic the JavaScript standard, e.g., Java, C#, C++, iOS, Android, et al.

The Kaazing Gateway has C#/.NET bindings for WebSocket.  Here's the 4.0 binary: http://developer.kaazing.com/downloads/byop-edition-download/

Search for "Kaazing" in Github to get the src.

Full disclosure:  I work for Kaazing.